# I keep getting object has no attribute error in python

Tags: python, urllib

I'm using python 3 but i've got python 2 on my computer also so I've been 
installing all my modules with pip3. I keep getting attribute errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ro/autoblg.py", line 3, in <module>
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

here is my code on the last bit of code I wrote

```
import urllib

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

print(htmltext)
```

It keeps doing it with other modules I already have installed.

Comment: How do you know which version of python this is running under?

Comment: I've done sudo pip3 install urllib3 and it says it's already installed and I'm running it python3 because I get an error when I don't use brackets on my print statement.